# How to match any symbol including a line terminator?

Tags: java, regex

I have a text "text abc". When I use the "(.+) abc" pattern, I'm found a match "text", it is ok. But if I use a second pattern, "([.]{1,}) abc", matcher doesn't found any match. Why?

I want use brace [], because I want use also a break line symbol (e.g., now I can't match "text \n abc" with first pattern.

Sorry for my bad English

See also DOTALL pattern: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL

My code:

```
    String text = "text abc";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.+) abc");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(text);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

PS: my goal is using somesing like "([.\n]{1,}) abc" pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not clear what you are trying to match, but if i understand correctly your problem is with "text \n abc". That's because of the newline to fix this use this

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.+) abc", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Pattern.DOTALL flag for "." to match even \r or \n.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, the pattern `([.\n]{1,}) abc` is rather backwards. First off, the `{1,}` is identical to `+`, so this pattern is really `([.\n]+) abc`. Secondly, as stated in the Oracle regex tutorials:

> Note: In certain situations the special characters listed above will not be treated as metacharacters.

In the case `[.]`, `.` is no longer a regex meta character. You can verify this by testing the pattern against the string `"test . abc"`, which will group `"."`.

To enable the `DOTALL` flag, just add the parameter to the regex or you can add the option as a parameter:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?s)(.+) abc")
```

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.+) abc", Pattern.DOTALL)
```

---

[Note reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/literals.html)

[Full list of flags and other useful information](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pattern.html)